# Grub badly confused; jumps between drives during boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I've spent about two weeks now trying to get a box that was running 10.04 to run 14.04. One of the ongoing problems that has been absolutely maddening is that GRUB has been acting really strangely.

For the past few days, I've been trying to get an alternative install of 14.04 in place so I could work on the primary one. (Primary is /dev/sda6, alt is /dev/sda3.) I would make the partition, copy files over or sometimes get a USB install to work or in one case put a (different) drive in a different machine to get the installation in place and then dropping it back into this box. Then, booting into the /sda6, I'd run update-grub, which would CLAIM that it saw both installations.

But when I rebooted, the alternative install wasn't available on the menu.

So I'd edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg by hand, and reboot. The menu wouldn't change. I would look at it again; my edits were still there, but grub was ignoring the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file on /sda6. Nor was it using /sda3's /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Sometimes there was another drive in the system, but it didn't have *any* grub.cfg files.

That was a few days ago. I managed to get the /sda6 install booting with everything except the GUI (because, as has become abundantly clear, Ubuntu 14.04's drivers for my ATI video are completely screwed up, but that's a different issue). I put an .iso file for Mythbuntu on my alternative partition, prepped it with grml-rescueboot, and ran update-grub. It counted through the usual vz and init files on the boot, the two mem-tests, and then said it found the grml .iso. Okay.

Reboot. Do I get the GRUB menu? Nope. It just went right into the /sda6 installation. I made change after change to grub.cfg and to /etc/default/grub (changing the default number, and many other things, and running update-grub after doing so). No change. I tried booting off my USB stick; it still went right into /sda6. I tried to change the boot order to get the USB stick to go first, and found that the machine's BIOS didn't recognize it as bootable.

So I took the USB stick back over to the other Ubuntu machine (running 12.04), and used Unetbootin to copy the 64-bit server .iso back onto it.

I stick it back into the machine I'm trying to upgrade, and boot. THIS time, I get a grub menu. But, I get the grub menu that's on /sda6! WTF??? When the hard drive (/sda) is the 'first' boot device, grub completely ignores the files on /sda6, but when I boot with the USB stick, THEN it uses the hard drive's /boot files?

Fine. I choose the Mythbuntu .iso off the menu. It boots into that. Which does me no good, because the screen started flashing and blinking, and after ten minutes, went totally black. That would be the broken video driver screwing things up.

I reboot again. Either grub or the Mythbuntu installer has destroyed the USB's boot records, because once again, I was not shown a grub boot menu, but instead watched it boot right back onto /sda6. (At the moment, that consists of seeing a Lubuntu startup screen for about five seconds, and then the screen goes black. The end.)

The machine does have a DVD drive. It's almost certainly malfunctioning; booting off CD/DVD is not an option. Nor can I move /sda to my other computer. /dev/sda is a hardware RAID5 array with five drives.

I've run update-grub more times than I can count, I've run grub-install, and grub-bios-install, I've worked with fdisk, parted, and gdisk, and even used the firmware on the RAID card to completely wipe a secondary drive so that I could try a totally clean-from-scratch install of grub onto that. I don't think grub has ever booted this system correctly.

I'm now seriously considering just calling Ubuntu 14.04 an unmitigated disaster, restoring 10.04 from my backups, and leaving it alone, since 10.04 ran without major issues on this box for four years, unless somebody can shed some light on how to get grub to do its job correctly, or point me at something besides grub that would work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Looking at the USB stick, the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file on it is trashed; it's just a bunch of binary garbage. I mounted the .iso; there's nothing wrong with the original version. Regrettably, I don't have a way to make the USB stick read-only.

Comment: I went through the entire drama-laden process again when trying to get from 14.04 to 16.04, and what eventually became clear is that, incomprehensibly, the hardware RAID system and Grub simply weren't compatible. Grub said it had installed on the array volume, but upon reboot, no menu or anything would appear. It just hung. Eventually I had the controller present the drives individually, and now the system boots into a mdadm soft RAID5 array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Grub2, and all of your OS are installed (no live usb with iso) you can always get Grub Customizer.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my main computer, Ubuntu and mint on my external hard, and mint on a flash drive (all fully installed) and when I connected all of them and then ran grub customizer it detected every single one, no problems.

An alternative solution would be to maybe use plop boot manager or super grub2. They will detect the OS on your computer and run them. Again, super grub2 will not detect live ISO.